# Randomize the value of a field between pre-stated values

Tags: java, random

It's my first post here and I'm also very new to Java.

I've created a Class called "Fish" that got the fields name, size and colour. I'm trying to find out how to write in the constructor so that it randomize a colour from a set of different colours I state somewhere in the code.

Anyone have an idea of how I should do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have your tried already? Please post some code.

Comment: You do yourself a disservice by asking such questions without first trying yourself. It's in those first attempts that you learn to code.

Comment: You might be correct that it in a way is a disservice but this is a bit ahead of the class and I really had no idea where to start. Got two examples below now that I can evaluate and learn and then do some examples on my own.

Answer (score 2):

store the values in a List which you can populate elsewhere.  then in your constructor you can just do:

```
private final Random random = new Random();


public YourConstructor()
{
   ...

   this.color = aColorList.get( random.nextInt() % aColorList.size() );

   ...
}
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks will try do it in this way as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
int select = (int)(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
if(select == 1) this.colour = "red";
else if(select == 2) this.colour = "blue";
else if(select == 3) this.colout = "green";
...
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks! The logic seems pretty easy. Will try it out right away.